Google Analytics 4 Custom Event issue
Im attempting to create an event in Google Analytics that will allow me to view recent sign ups and be able to get an exact number of sign ups, but the problem revolves around the sendGAEvent not working, and yes my layout.tsx has the  component from @next/third-parties/google and has my correct id, I just figure out why its not working.
  const handleSignUp = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
  
    if (!validatePassword(password)) {
      setMessage("Password must be at least 6 characters and include a special character.");
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      if (await isUsernameTaken(username)) {
        setMessage("Username is taken, please choose another one.");
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }
  
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const newUser = userCredential.user;
  
      if (newUser) {
        await updateProfile(newUser, { displayName: displayName });
        const randomLogo = logos[Math.floor(Math.random() * logos.length)];
  
        await setDoc(doc(db, "usernames", username.toLowerCase()), { uid: newUser.uid });
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", newUser.uid), {
          uid: newUser.uid,
          email: newUser.email,
          displayName: displayName,
          username: username.toLowerCase(),
          logo: randomLogo,
          createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
          lastSignInAt: Timestamp.now(),
        });
        sendGAEvent('User', 'sign_up', 'User Sign Up');
        onSignInSuccess();
        router.push("/lounge");
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      setMessage(error.message);
      console.error("Error creating user", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

I've tried using the DebugView to ensure that my events were getting through, but no signs. In the network tab displays my Google Analytics code as well the 204.
